# How to convert intArray to ArrayList<Int> in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

From

```
val array = intArrayOf(5, 3, 0, 2, 4, 1, 0, 5, 2, 3, 1, 4)
```

I need to convert to `ArrayList<Int>`

I have tried `array.toTypedArray()`

But it converted to `Array<Int>` instead

Comment: It is worth scanning the API references for Kotlin stdlib where you'll find a lot of useful functions such as `toList()` ... http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use [`toCollection`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-collection.html) function and specify `ArrayList` as a mutable collection to fill:

```
val arrayList = intArrayOf(1, 2, 5).toCollection(ArrayList())
```

Comment: this is the intended API

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky It should. You can try this code on play.kotlinlang.org: https://pl.kotl.in/9s_sfYftP

Comment: @Ilya how u create short url on kotlin obline compiler?

Answer (score 22):

You can get `List<Int>` with a simple [`toList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-list.html) call like so:

```
val list = intArrayOf(5, 3, 0, 2).toList()
```

However if you really need `ArrayList` you can create it too:

```
val list = arrayListOf(*intArrayOf(5, 3, 0, 2).toTypedArray())
```

or using more idiomatic Kotlin API as suggested by [@Ilya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40045644/155213):

```
val arrayList = intArrayOf(1, 2, 5).toCollection(ArrayList())
```

Or if you'd like to do the above yourself and save some allocations:

```
val arrayList = intArrayOf(5, 3, 0, 2).let { intList ->
    ArrayList<Int>(intList.size).apply { intList.forEach { add(it) } }
}
```

Comment: please see the @ilya's answer for idiomatic API usage